# Django: adding multiple values to a model's field

Tags: python, django, database-design, model

I am new to Django. I am trying to create an app with news, and the companies mentioned in those news, and have created the following models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.orgn_name 



class News(models.Model):
    news_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    news_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    news_date = models.DateField()
    news_company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_title
```

Now, a news might have mention of more than one company. How do I account for that, and enter the list of companies in the database entry? I am using the default Sqlite DB right now.

E.g. a news can be *"Facebook competes with Google in AI space"* This news has two companies: Facebook and Google.

1) How do I design my models so that they take multiple values for `Company`?

2) How do I save those values via shell?

3) How do I query it, so that a query similar to `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT 'Company')....` should output **Facebook** and **Google** separately, and not as **"Facebook, Google"**?

I am stuck here and desperately need some guidance. TIA

Comment: Your model seems right. You just need to study couple of django tutorial for 3 questions you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The models you created are fine and can use them. Lets go step by step,

1. Lets create an instance of the `Company` model:

   `c = Company(company_name="Facebook", country_name="USA")
   c.save()`
2. Now lets create an instance of the `News` model:

   `n = News(news_title="AI", news_link="Link", news_date="date")`
3. Now we have to associate the `Company` with the `News`. This can be done as:

   `n.news_company.add(c)`
4. Now for querying, we can write it as follows:

   `News.objects.filter(news_company__name="Facebook")`

This will return all the news for the company Facebook.

Hope this gives you a head start. For more in depth coverage, read this [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: Thanks. I got it till here. if there are following two companies:
`c=Company(company_name="Facebook",country_name="USA")`
`g=Company(company_name="Google",country_name="USA")`

Then... while associating the company with the news, should I write:


n.news_company.add(c,g).... or...

`n.news_company.add(c)`
`n.news_company.add(g)`
`n.save()..... `

will it enter both the companies, and retrieve them separately?

Comment: Yes you can do n.news_company.add(c,g), it will associate it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Am trying that